# jquery with json change html part

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery function which returns a total value of a shopping cart. The function looks like this:

```
  function bakVormTotals(targetClass){

      $.getJSON('http://shop.com/cart/?format=json', function(data){

           $.each(data.cart, function(index, totals){
                $('<strong/>').html('€' + totals.grand_total + '').appendTo(targetClass); // the   grand total price
           });
      });
  }
```

Everything works fine except that the outcome of totals.grand_total is

```
€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€undefined€2404.00
```

Where €2404.00 is the correct value. Probably I have to get rid of the html part since this keeps returning the value. Is this correct? Is there a way to fix this problem?

My json looks like this (minified) if this may help.

```
"totals":{"sub_total":"2020.17","taxes":[{"percentage":"0.1900","amount":383.83}],"grand_total":"2404.00"}}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you should do `totals.totals.grand_total` :

```
 $('<strong/>').html('€' + totals.totals.grand_total + '').appendTo(targetClass);
```

Comment: that returns totals.totals is undefined. Maybe my issue is because of the "each" function? What I really want is perhaps create a variable and do something with that so I can leave .html('€' + totals.totals.grand_total + '') out of the code?!

Comment: @JaapVermoolen try `$.each(data.cart.totals` then `totals.grand_total`

Comment: this returns just €undefined€undefined€undefined without the correct value